# swift2.1でマップアプリのaddAnnotationした際に呼ばれるデリゲートメソッド

Tags: ios, swift

swift2.1を使ってannotationをカスタマイズして画像を貼ろうと思っていますが、サンプルプログラムを実行してもMKCircleは出るんですが、ピンとカスタマイズした画像が表示されません。
swift2.1になって何か変更点が出て実行できないのでしょうか？

[image: スクリーンショット]

[007 アノテーションに画像を追加-swift Docs](https://sites.google.com/a/gclue.jp/swift-docs/ni-yinki100-ios/7-mapkit/anoteshonni-hua-xiangwo-zhui-jia)

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    // 経度緯度.
    let myLan: CLLocationDegrees = 37.331741
    let myLon: CLLocationDegrees = -122.030333

    var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // 地図の中心の座標.
        center = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(myLan, myLon)

        // mapViewを生成.
        var myMapView: MKMapView = MKMapView()
        myMapView.frame = self.view.frame
        myMapView.center = self.view.center
        myMapView.centerCoordinate = center
        myMapView.delegate = self

        // 縮尺を指定.
        let mySpan: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1)
        let myRegion: MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: mySpan)

        // regionをmapViewに追加.
        myMapView.region = myRegion

        // viewにmapViewを追加.
        self.view.addSubview(myMapView)

        // 円を描画する(半径500m).
        let myCircle: MKCircle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: center, radius: CLLocationDistance(500))

        // mapViewにcircleを追加.
        myMapView.addOverlay(myCircle)

        // centerを指すアノテーションを生成.
        let myPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        myPointAnnotation.title = "title"
        myPointAnnotation.subtitle = "subtitle"
        myPointAnnotation.coordinate = center

        // mapViewにアノテーションを追加.
        myMapView.addAnnotation(myPointAnnotation)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    /*
    addAnnotationした際に呼ばれるデリゲートメソッド.
    */
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

        // Identifier生成.
        let myAnnotationIdentifier: NSString = "myAnnotation"

        // アノテーション生成.
        var myAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView!

        // もしアノテーションがまだインスタンス化されていなかったらインスタンスを生成する.
        if myAnnotationView == nil {

            myAnnotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: myAnnotationIdentifier as String)

            // アノテーションに画像を追加.
            myAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sample.jpg"))

            // アノテーションのコールアウトを許可.
            myAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        }

        return myAnnotationView
    }

    /*
    addOverlayした際に呼ばれるデリゲートメソッド.
    */
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {

        // rendererを生成.
        let myCircleView: MKCircleRenderer = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)

        // 円の内部を青色で塗りつぶす.
        myCircleView.fillColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        // 円を透過させる.
        myCircleView.alpha = 0.5

        // 円周の線の太さ.
        myCircleView.lineWidth = 0.5

        return myCircleView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C側のAPIに`nullable`/`nonnull`が追加されたことで、iOS9 SDKでは`!`のついていた多くのAPIが変更されています。

実際にコードを書くと警告が出ると思うのですが、以下の通りに修正する必要があります。

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    // 現在地を示すアノテーションではnilを返却し、規定の挙動にする
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    // Identifier
    let myAnnotationIdentifier = "myAnnotation"

    // AnnotationViewをdequeue
    var myAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView! = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(myAnnotationIdentifier)

    if myAnnotationView == nil {
        myAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: myAnnotationIdentifier)
        myAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "sample.jpg"))
        myAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
    }

    return myAnnotationView
}
```

これはサンプルコードになぜか書いていないので補足になりますが、

- `MKAnnotationView`は`dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:`を利用しないと再利用できません。（毎回`View`を生成することになり、`identifier`の意味もありません）
- ただの`MKAnnotationView`はサブクラスで独自にアノテーションを作る場合に使うものなので、ピンを表示するのであれば`MKPinAnnotationView`を使う必要があります。

Comment: このコードに置き換えたところ画像は表示されたんですが、現在地を表示している青い丸もピンに変わってしまうんですが、どうしたら良いでしょう？

Comment: @sugawara  現在地を表示している青い丸もアノテーションなのです。このデリゲートメソッドでは`MKPinAnnotationView`だけを返却しているので、置き換わってしまいます。とりあえず、回答に現在地の青い丸をデフォルトに戻す処理を含めてみました。これらのメソッドの完璧な実装には、MapKitの理解が必要で大変かもしれませんが、リファレンスなど参照してみて頑張ってください。